# Setting in php that allows loose translation of variables?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, centos, server

I have an application and database that is currently running on one of GoDaddy's servers and it runs great. I recently decided to create my own Centos box for hosting of said application and database. I'm a relative Newbie when it comes to setting up a Linux box, but have found many good articles online. Everything installed fine and am able to access the application, it runs queries and displays pages accordingly.

However, I have found that inserts into certain tables are no longer working. The database and its tables are setup correctly and permissions are set accordingly, from an access perspective. The problem appears when I try to insert a new record into a table where a column requires an integer and the insert statement is only passing a blank variable. The same insert works fine on the GoDaddy server but not on my server. Is there a setting in php or a module for either mysql or php that I need to install or set?

For example; a form passes the string variable payment type as '4' and when I try to insert it into the database, I get incorrect integer value. This leads me to believe that either the php is not doing some sort of loose translation of the POST variable or the the mysql is running in some sort of strict rules.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It could be a lot of things: incompatible database collations, not null columns, php casting problems... both GoDaddy's server and your box got the same php and database versions?

Answer (score 1):

After researching further into settings for mysql, I found that the default for the database has a STRICT_TRANS_TABLES setting for the sql_mode in /etc/my.cnf and by removing that tag, everything worked great.